# Website redirect error thingy

Tags: web, dns

um, I made a website about a day ago and I registered my domain with CrazyDomains. I updated the name servers to my web host (000webhost.com) and saved the changes. I thought that this would make it so that if I type my website's name in the URL bar without "www." at the front it would take me to my website but... well... typing my website's URL without the "www." at the front just takes me to a CrazyDomains page. I want users to be able to access my website without having to type the "www." for it to work but it seems that this is the only current way to access it. I dunno what to do!! Somebody helllllppp!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is entirely up to the service that **provided** the domain (CrazyDomains in your case), where to put people - that absolutely includes subdomains like "www.".

It seems that CrazyDomain really only assigned you to the subdomain and did not give you the actual thing. I have no idea about their terms but if the domain itself redirects visitors to **their** site, they did not really give you a domain but only a subdomain...

Check their terms and check all configuration options they give you.

Comment: Thanks!! I looked at it some more, it was most likely because I hadn't uploaded any files yet or something. Anyways, i don't know how, but now it magically redirects to the correct page. :D and thank you again :)